# How to 'SELECT FROM {entity_bundle} WHERE field_A + field_B <= given_number_X' with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'MYCONTENTTYPE')

// Now say for instance I would like to grab the value of
// field_A and field_B, sum them up ( or subtract | divide | multiply them ).
// Then compare the result of that ( is greater than, equals to, smaller than )
// with a given number X. Is it possible with EntityFieldQuery?

$query_result = $query->execute();
```

I know I could do that by looping through the query result. Nontheless, if EntityFieldQuery allows me to do that at query time, I would like to know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont believe you can do this with the core methods provided by the [EFQ api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

But, you may always extend the default EFQ class with a version of your own. Or, you may implement a function such as [hook_entity_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_query_alter/7) or the [addTag()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3aaddTag/7) method of EFQ.

Using `addTag` for instance on the EFQ you could then also implement [hook_query_TAG_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) and alter the `SelectQuery` that is ultimately called from the original EFQ and alter the base query to include your additional (non-standard) logic.

This could look like this short example, we additionally use the [SelectQuery::where()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3awhere/7) method:

```
// Within some function of yours, you execute your query; giving it a Tag.
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'MYCONTENTTYPE')
  // Must call the method fieldCondition on field_A and field_B so
  // they get included in the SQL INNER JOIN statement.
  ->fieldCondition('field_A')
  ->fieldCondition('field_B')
  ->addTag('DoFunkyFieldLogic');
$query_result = $query->execute();

// ... elsewhere in your custom module ...

// Implements hook_query_TAG_alter
function mymodule_query_DoFunkyFieldLogic_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('DoFunkyFieldLogic')) {
    // You will likely need to install Devel and call dpm($query) here.
    // Or else you wont know what the field names are in the raw SQL ...
    // you might be able to cheat and use full database table names and
    // column names, eg:
    //dpm($query);
    $query->where("field_data_field_A1.field_A_value + field_data_field_B2.field_B_value <= :my_quantity", array(':my_quantity' => variable_get('my_quantity', 5));
  }
}
```

There may be cleaner ways to do this -- but this approach is relatively straight forward. This code is untested; but should work.

Comment: Awesome! your solution does the trick, thanks. I had to do a minor correction though.

Comment: @FranciscoLuz whats the correction so i can amend the post ? (or feel free to Edit the post as well) ...

Comment: Weird. I've edited your answer but it's not there anymore. Here it is, http://bit.ly/13WOp4O

Comment: Basically you have to call fieldCondition on field_A and field_B otherwise your get a nasty error.

Comment: ah i see, i approved the edit. Yes including the `fieldCondition` will add the join for your ... it's basically your choice (and probably wise) to include it that way for later processing. You could always just `addJoin` on the `SelectQuery` itself ... good catch.

Comment: Ya ! It's very cool. We can use the same way for db_select, db_update, db_select.